# Error: Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, arrays, object

I'm getting an error:

> Trying to get property of non-object on line 30

On the commented line below...

```
function admin_trim_category_description( $terms, $taxonomies ){
    if( 'category' != $taxonomies[0] ) return $terms;
    $my_categories = array('item1','item2','item3');
    foreach( $terms as $key => $term)
        if(in_array(
            $terms[$key]->name, //ERROR LINE HERE
            $my_categories)) 
            {
                unset($terms[$key]);   
            }
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Exactly what it says: `$terms[$key]` is not an object. Have you tried a `var_dump`?

Comment: Probably you want `$terms[$key]['name']`

Comment: Code-style wise, I'm wondering why you're doing `$terms[$key]->name` not `$term->name` but that's not going to affect this problem..

Answer (score 0):

`$terms[$key]` seems not to be an object. I'd suggest you to check whatever it is an object or not with:

```
if (is_object($terms[$key])) { /* OK */ }
```

and/or check whatever the object is an instance of a specific class with:

```
if ($terms[$key] instanceof MyClass) { /* OK */ }
```